# what are index partitioning and mirror query components in SharePoint2010 Search?

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

what are index partitioning and mirror query components in SharePoint2010 Search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [an excellent, gentle introduction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/04/23/search-2010-architecture-and-scale-part-2-query.aspx) from an MSDN blog